# Convert Pandas Columns to Decimal128

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get data prepped to be uploaded to MongoDB. From experiments on another day, I learned that I need to convert float values to Decimal128 before sending it up to a MongoDB collection. I am finding posts for the inverse of what I am trying to do.

My code is working. But because I am working with so much data, it takes a long time to run. **If anyone feels like sharing a faster/better way to complete this operation, it would be greatly appreciated.**

I am going to move the ".replace(',', '')" operation outside of the function used in apply. I just haven't done so yet as I am still waiting for the code to complete for the first time.

```
from bson import Decimal128

def snap_convert_decimal(row):
   try:
       for col in dec_cols :
           if row[col] is not None:
               row[col] = Decimal128(str(row[col]).replace(',', '')) 
       return row
   except:
       # just using this to figure out where things were failing
       print(col)
       print(row[col])
       assert False


dec_cols = ['col1', 'col2','col3']

snap_df[dec_cols ] = snap_df[dec_cols ].apply(snap_convert_decimal, axis = 1)
```

Comment: what is dec_cols?

Comment: "decimal columns".

Comment: added an answer, see if it works for you. share feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# use applymap to apply lambda for the selected columns
# check if the value has only digits comma and decimal point
# when true, remove the comma
# when false, return as is

df[dec_cols]=(df[dec_cols] 
                .applymap(lambda x : Decimal128(re.sub(r',','', str(x)))  
                          if re.match(r'^[\d\.,]+$', str(x) )  
                          else x))
df
```

Comment: Hey thank you! This cut the time from 25 minutes to 8 minutes for the run time. 
I was on vacation, sorry for just getting back to this.